# How to use a PBD in a PowerBuilder Library

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a PBD file that I want to use in a PowerBuilder Library. I'm not really certain how to accomplish this. I've added the PBD to the library list and the application will run. However, when the method is called, it throws a bad runtime function reference.

I'm using PowerBuilder Classic 12.0 Build 5530 and trying to use the PbniRegex Extension.

http://sebastien.kirche.free.fr/powerbuilder/en.html

Comment: Which version of PowerBuilder are you using? That might be useful for us to know.

Comment: No problem. I've updated the question with the information.

Comment: Not possible as PBD is semi-compiled code.

Comment: @somnath: What is not possible? Of course you can add a PBD to a target, you only won't be able to see any source code, but you can call objets that are provided.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Seki. It has been many years I used PB and this info clearly then has left my brain's KB! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put the `pbniregex.pbx` with the corresponding `.pbd` with the files of the project? The `.pbx`is actually a dll and the `.pbd` is only a wrapper to declare its methods to PB.